# Anyone have an ERD symbols quick reference?

Tags: database-design, notation, erd

I'm looking for a one-page quick-reference or cheatsheet (preferably in PDF) to the meanings of the various ERD symbols in Crowsfoot/Martin notation.

I've done a lot of googling, but have not found a good, concise quick-reference guide, though I'm sure one must exist.

Comment: Hi wadesworld! None of the other answers pointed to a single-page reference, so I went ahead and built one. Let me know if that's along the lines of what you were looking for. Cheers!

Comment: I searched for "sql database association symbols" and found [ER Diagram Symbols & Notation | Lucidchart](https://www.lucidchart.com/pages/ER-diagram-symbols-and-meaning). That page probably was not there when this question was asked but now there are web pages such as that with the material.

Comment: Is there a Unicode version of any of these?  Especially the crow's foot symbol?

Answer (score 83):

I've also been looking for a single-page "quick reference" PDF for ERD relationship symbols (i.e. "Crows Feet"). I haven't found anything I've liked, so I created this.

I've posted the [Full Page, Printable PDF](http://www.vivekmchawla.com/erd-crows-foot-relationship-symbols-cheat-sheet) on my blog.

Hope this helps! 
[image: ERD "Crow's Foot" Relationship Notation Quick Reference]

Answer (score 24):

This one is very good explanation:

[image: Entity relationship model explanation]

Comment: Who made this diagram and where did you find it? Please provide attribution.

Comment: From a Google reverse image search, it looks like this came from Oracle's "Java Stored Procedures Developer's Guide" from 1999: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/F49540_01/DOC/java.815/a64686/05_dev1.htm#18622